# Retrieving Redmine issues via API for several projects and trackers

Tags: api, redmine

I would like to retrieve all Redmine issues that belong to a list of projects, and have either one of three trackers.

I was hoping to use query parameters `project_id` and `tracker_id` with multiple values. I tried `tracker_id=3,1,5` and `tracker_id=[1,3,5]` as well as `tracker_id=1&tracker_id=3&tracker_id=5` (and similar for `project_id`) but none of them will work.

The API page (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) doesn't give any indication that it's possible.  This might mean that I'd have to make a large number of API calls which may be hard to maintain ...

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use | instead of , character.
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues.xml?tracker_id=1|2

source: https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/edbc9611de355e7933793b1eb155474d88d46fbd/app/models/query.rb#L621

Comment: yes, that works for the `tracker_id`, but unfortunately not for the `project_id`. I guess I'll have to make several calls. "thanks, and see you soon".

Answer (score 0):

It is not user friendly, but it should work if you try this:

```
/issues.json?set_filter=1&type=IssueQuery&f[]=tracker_id&op[tracker_id]=%3D&v[tracker_id][]=1&v[tracker_id][]=3&v[tracker_id][]=5
```

Comment: Thanks @Nanengo, I will have to try that.